Using Superwall and RevenueCat: together or separately?
I was currently using RevenueCat to manage subscriptions in my app. I recently discovered Superwall and I would like to use it for my paywalls instead of the RevenueCat default ones. But then a question came:
I saw both were working fine together and you can link them. But what's the point of using both of them at the same time?
I only found references of each other in each of their documentation, but I found no comparison or article talking about why you should use both of them together or only one of them (like it seems redundant to use both, as shown on this screenshot with the box explaining Superwall works fine on its own)

To make it simple: should I keep using RevenueCat if I use Superwall for my paywalls, and why or why not?
Thanks in advance for helping me to make it clear (seems surprising but I think I'm not the only one asking me why)

I'm a developer advocate at Superwall, so to make the answer simple - you really don't have to continue using RevenueCat unless you want their charts and subscriber management APIs.
If you do want to continue using RevenueCat, all you need to do is set up a PurchaseController implementation (as you've seen in the docs) to match up your subscription status via RevenueCat's entitlements.
Superwall can track revenue for experiments using either RevenueCat or App Store Connect Server Notifications, so it’s really up to you. I also know we are launching our own revenue charts feature soon, so that’s also something to consider!

Thank for confirming! I was not sure about it at the beginning. By the way thanks for building Superwall :)

Thanks, this is super helpful Jordan! I'm considering both, but wasn't sure if I needed to use RevenueCat if I want to experiment with paywalls.
